# Como subir una imagen creada con PHP

Tags: php

Estimados tengo la siguiente duda, estoy realizando la siguiente prueba. La cual es crear un recuadro color rojo y subirlo al servidor, en este caso localhost.

```
<?php
$imagenroja = imagecreate (300,300); //cuadrado de 300 x 300 píxeles
$color_fondo = imagecolorallocate ($imagenroja, 255, 0, 0); //rgb color rojo
imagepng($imagenroja,'../imagenes/cuadro.png');
?>
```

Como podria subir esa imagen creada, pero usando move_uploaded_file

Comment: ¿Subirla adónde? El método `imagepng` ya está guardando la imagen en una ruta de tu servidor.

Comment: Esa era mi duda, cual es la diferencia de usar move_uploaded_file

Comment: Pues que `imagepng` crea una imagen en el servidor y la guarda donde le indiques, en cambio `move_uploaded_file` mueve un archivo subido por el cliente a una carpeta del servidor. En principio es clara la diferencia, el cómo vayas a usar alguno o ambos de estos métodos ya es cuestión de la lógica de tu aplicación. De antemano te indico que `move_uploaded_file` *intenta asegurarse de que el archivo designado por `filename` es un archivo subido válido (lo que significa que fue subido mediante el mecanismo de subida HTTP POST de PHP)*. El archivo generado por `imagepng` no sería válido. Saludos